# FFT Magnitude Output

Tags: fft

I'm just getting into signal processing and need to do some DFT/FFT work.

If I take a signal with two freqs of 2Hz and 5Hz: x(t)=sin(2*2pi*t)+sin(5*2pi*t).  I sample at 100Hz for 5 sec (so my DFT size is 500).

Because my inputs are real values I get a symmetric DFT, so can discard the 2nd half and convert the DFT values into magnitude by doing sqrt(re^2+c^2).

My bin widths are 100/500 = 0.2Hz, and so I get: [image]

With peaks at 2Hz and 5Hz as expected.

My question is: why are the magnitudes different?

On a related note, why are there not two perfect spikes at 2hz and 5Hz, i.ee the graph has non-zero values at 1.5 and 2.5 etc.  Is this spectral leakage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect your 500 data points are being processed as a 512 point FFT (most FFT libraries do not support arbitrary size inputs and so typically they zero pad to the next highest power of 2). If that is the case then you will be seeing the effects of [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage). Applying a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to the FFT should fix this. Note that you will still see "skirts" on either side of your peaks - this is due to the uncertainty introduced by a finite sampling window.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct the FFT was extending it to 512 points